# What kind of items I can receive in inbox on the top bar?

Tags: support, notifications, top-bar, global-inbox

As I know, if there are updates on my own question, SE will send me messages in inbox. But if I start a bounty in other's question, it is not. I am confused. What kind of items I can receive in inbox?
[image: The inbox is here]

Answer (score 2):

It includes these items:

- Answers on your own questions
- Comments on your own posts
- Edits on your own posts
- Bounty expiration
- Chats
- Elections

Comment: And *comments on somebody's post* if someone tags you using @.

Comment: Yes. In the case, the user will receive message in inbox. The 2nd item which is "Comments on your own posts" includes this case.